# Fake IP use Other Server

Tags: windows, networking, server, network-programming, centos

I have 2 server, 1 server game use Windows Server 2008 R2 OS and 1 server fake ip use Windows Server 2008 R2 or CentOS. I wanna make may IP server game hide with my server fake IP.

Is that possible if I wanna like that? If Possible what tools I must use for make my IP server game become fake IP?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no - the network wouldn't know where to send the packets. You could try but you would get 'IP Address Conflict' warnings/errors. Two machines on the same network can't share the same IP address. You could use [IP Masq](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/ipmasq-background2.5.html) on *nix maybe possible on windows to achieve something like what you're talking about. What are you actually trying to achieve - why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I just wanna make my server game IP totally hide